# Expose API for Microsoft Power BI or Tableau

Tags: api, powerbi, tableau-api

I have a SaaS application that generates data that would be really valuable for my customers to get insights into. Especially because the data is theirs and I know it would help them to improve their daily work to be able to dive into this data.

But I would very much prefer not to have to build a BI tool into my application as this is not my primary business, and I also know that my imagination is limited in terms of what they want to do with the data.

So I thought I would expose some API endpoints that expose the data, so it can be consumed by Microsoft Power BI or Tableau. But I haven't been able to find any blog posts or documentation on the best way to structure such API endpoints both in the JSON structure and the authentication model.

Should I for example include paging in my API? Should I protect the API with OAuth or opt in for a security by obscurity model?

I would also like to provide people with a sample Power BI Dashboard if that is possible. For now I think my primary target will be Power BI.

Any links and thoughts are much appreciated.